# How to open a modal dialog with angular ui router and keep the current view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to follow [this approach](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-open-a-dialogmodal-at-a-certain-state) and everything seem to work, however it has a nasty side effect, since the ui-view under the dialog becomes blank.

Is there a way to follow that approach and keep intact the view under the dialog?